# How to manipulate attributes of an object passed to a function without mutating the state

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming

I would like to know if is possible to change attributes of an object passed to a function without mutating the state of the object.

Something like this:

```
function startOfLine(options) {
  options.someProp = += 'startOfLine';
  return options;
}

function otherFunction(options) {
  // do something with options and...
  return options;
}

const options = startOfLine(otherFunction({
  somePro: '',
  someProp2: ''
}));
```

I'm going to create the execution of the functions in a dynamic way, that's why i'm not worry about nesting 20 levels of calls.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between "change" and "mutate" for you? You can hardly do one without the other. If you want immutability, you have to create a new object (with the nes state) and return that.

Comment: Is it possible to measure the performance of creating an object in each function vs mutating the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to update an object in functional languages, the usual approach is to return a new cloned version of the object with some of the properties changes (without modifying the original object). I do not think there is a built-in way to clone object in JavaScript but [this post provides a detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object). Using the `clone` function from that answer you can write:

```
function startOfLine(options) {
  var newOptions = clone(options);
  newOptions.someProp = 'startOfLine';
  return newOptions;
}
```

When you have object `o1` and you write `var o2 = startOfLine(o1)` then you get back a new object `o2` with `startOfLine` settings but without mutating `o1`.

If you are not mutating the object anywhere, you can perform shallow copy (and avoid cloning the entire object tree), but there is still some overhead involved - but you get the nice properties of working with immutable objects that often outweight the costs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not have sufficient reputation to post a comment.
So trying to answer based on some reasonable assumptions.

You are looking a way to chain some operations related a single object with better efficiency avoiding too much mutation or creation of new objects. The final object should the same object (or a copy?) with applied transformations.

If this is the one you are looking for, it can be done with a good memory efficiency by using Hash trees.
You can refer to the library immutable.js by Facebook

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/